# Save multiple checkbox rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, multiple-checkout

I have multiple checkbox that I need to save in a mysql DB table.
He managed to keep all the form fields except multiples checkboxes.
I need to serialize save them, how I can do?

*_form.html.erb*

```
        <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :news_source, 'Noticias', :class => 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <%= f.label :news_source, 'El País' %>
        <%= check_box_tag  "news_source[]", '1' %>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :news_source, 'El Observador' %>
        <%= check_box_tag  "news_source[]", '2' %>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :news_source, 'El Espectador' %>
        <%= check_box_tag  "news_source[]", '3' %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

With Scaffold create my controller

```
  def create
raise params.inspect
@emission = Emission.new(emission_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @emission.save
    format.html { redirect_to @emission, notice: 'La emisión fue creada correctamente.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @emission }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @emission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ActiveRecord::Base.serialize** [Reference Link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001799)

For example :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize : news_source_ids
end

user = Emission.create(:scholarship=> { "name" => "test", "news_source_ids" => ["1", "2"]})
Emission.find(usernews_source.id).scholarship# => { "name" => "test", "news_source_ids" => ["1", "2"] }
```